# Using liquid to sort posts alphabetically

Tags: filter, jekyll, liquid

Is there a way to sort a number of posts alphabetically, using Jekyll?

I have something like this now:

```
{% for post in site.categories.threat %}
<li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

It works, but the posts are jumbled up. Would look much nicer if they were sorted alphabetically I think.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It **can** be done without a plugin, which means that it works with [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

You have to use some ugly string manipulation tricks, though.
I used a similar approach [to implement a tag page (that lists all posts for each tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002505/6884).

Same approach, slightly modified:

```
{% capture posts %}
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    |{{ post.title }}#{{ post.url }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign sortedposts = posts | split: '|' | sort %}
{% for post in sortedposts %}
    {% assign postitems = post | split: '#' %}
    <a href={{ postitems[1] }}">{{ postitems[0] }}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Beware:

You need **two** different separator characters inside the first loop *(and of course again in the `split` calls later on)*.
**In order for this to work, both characters must not occur in any of the post titles or URLs!!**

I'm using `|` and `#` in this example, which works for me *(I just tested it with my blog)*. But you might need to use different characters, depending on your post titles and how your URLs are constructed.

---

#### Bonus:

If you want to display only the posts in a certain tag/category *(and not all posts)*, you can change the first `for` loop *(the one inside the `capture`)* to one of these:

```
{% for post in site.tags['whatever'] %}

{% for post in site.categories['whatever'] %}
```

Comment: I have a question [here, regarding a quite similar matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707352/how-to-group-data-by-first-letter-from-a-csv-file-in-liquid).

Comment: Using the split on | I wound up with an empty first entry in the array, so I wrapped `{% unless forloop.first %} {% endunless %}` around the output to ignore it.

Answer (score 23):

According to the documentation, to filter an array by one of its field, you can use :

```
    {% assign sortedPosts = site.posts | sort: 'title' %}
```

Then the `sortedPosts` variable will contain the sorted array.

The documentation can be found here : https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#sort

Answer (score 11):

It's both clean and elegant to sort in Jekyll in GitHub pages without a plugin. Use your .yml data file in the _data directory. I use a data file here called `team-members.yml`:

```
{% assign sorted_team = site.data.team-members | sort:'title' %}
{% for member in sorted_team %}
    <span class="title">{{ member.title }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

This pattern will handle what you need to do here.

Comment: this worked perfect for me, I did with my post titles.

Answer (score 6):

I adapted a Jekyll plugin from https://gist.github.com/3812259 to accomplish this. I couldn't use the plugin as-is, because it failed in the presence of null values. I'm a beginning ruby programmer, and coded the null handling with help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/808721/1135052

sort_for example reversing the sort and performing case-sensitive string comparisons (ignored if the sorted property is not a string):

```
{% sorted_for node in site.pages reversed sort_by:title case_sensitive:true %}
  {{ node.title }}
{% endsorted_for %}
```

sorted_keys_for example:

```
{% sorted_keys_for tag in site.tags %}
  <a href="/tags/{{ tag | downcase | replace:" ","-"}}.html">{{ tag }}</a><br />
  Num posts: {{ site.tags[tag].size }}
{% endsorted_keys_for %}
```

For use in Jekyll, put this code in _plugins/sort_for.rb

```
module Jekyll
  module SortedForImpl
    def render(context)
      sorted_collection = collection_to_sort context
      return if sorted_collection.empty?
      sort_attr = @attributes['sort_by']
      case_sensitive = @attributes['case_sensitive'] == 'true'
      i = sorted_collection.first

      if sort_attr != nil
        if i.to_liquid[sort_attr].instance_of? String and not case_sensitive
          sorted_collection.sort_by! { |i|
            k = i.to_liquid[sort_attr]
            k ? k.downcase : ''
          }
        else
          sorted_collection.sort_by! { |i|
            k = i.to_liquid[sort_attr]
            [k ? 1 : 0,k || 1]
          }
        end
      else
        if i.instance_of? String and not case_sensitive
          sorted_collection.sort_by! { |i| i.downcase }
        else
          sorted_collection.sort!
        end
      end

      original_name = @collection_name
      result = nil
      context.stack do
        sorted_collection_name = "#{@collection_name}_sorted".sub('.', '_')
        context[sorted_collection_name] = sorted_collection
        @collection_name = sorted_collection_name
        result = super
        @collection_name = original_name
      end
      result
    end
  end

  class SortedForTag < Liquid::For
    include SortedForImpl

    def collection_to_sort(context)
      return context[@collection_name].dup
    end

    def end_tag
      'endsorted_for'
    end
  end

  class SortedKeysForTag < Liquid::For
    include SortedForImpl

    def collection_to_sort(context)
      return context[@collection_name].keys
    end

    def end_tag
      'endsorted_keys_for'
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('sorted_for', Jekyll::SortedForTag)
Liquid::Template.register_tag('sorted_keys_for', Jekyll::SortedKeysForTag)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for my simple table of contents, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add following for future reference.

To sort posts by title, you can use `sort` filter.
See http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters

So, this works:

```
{% assign sorted_threat_posts = site.categories.threat | sort: 'title', 'last' %}
{% for post in sorted_threat_posts %}
   <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't work for me. I'm using `{% assign sorted_team = site.data.team-members | sort: 'title', 'name' %}`  But I get compile errors:  `Liquid Exception: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)`

Answer (score 0):

i tested Christian's great solution in my local site: before the first row there is an empty link (i don't no why) in output, therefore the first link doesn't work, so i modified his code inserting `{% if postitems[1] %}` before the line `<a href={{ postitems[1] }}">{{ postitems[0] }}</a><br>`and an `{% endif %}` after. suggested [tanky woo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872861/jekyll-display-posts-by-category).

Answer (score -1):

It cannot be done without a plugin or custom function. Although, there is an ongoing effort to implement this in the next releases: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/101 and then it would look like:

```
{% for tag in site.tags order:ascending %} 
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

See also: [Order an array with Jekyll / liquid template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218769/order-an-array-with-jekyll-liquid-template)