# How to make list order ascending with Jekyll and Liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am starting with Liquid & Jekyll can anyone help me with making list order ascending (by {{category}} name)?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 patickaborder">
                <h5>Rubriky</h5>
                    <ul>
                        {% for category in site.categories order:ascending %}
                            <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ category | first }}/index.html">{{ category | first }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built-in way for ordering as of now, it's only possible with plugins.

The `order:ascending` syntax you're using in your question [will maybe work in the future, when this is implemented in Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11646814/6884).
In the same question, there's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14427073/6884) that shows how to sort with a [plugin *(which means that it won't work on GitHub Pages!)*](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/).

---

If you can't use or don't want to use a plugin, it's possible to do it without plugins...with some *really* ugly looking Liquid-foo.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002505/6884), where I'm ordering `site.tags` alphabetically to create a list of tags for my blog.

Answer (score 11):

Just found this out. You can sort the list and assign it to a variable, then use that in your markup, like this:

```
{% assign sortedcats = site.categories | sort %}

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 patickaborder">
    <h5>Rubriky</h5>
        <ul>
            {% for category in sortedcats %}
                <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ category | first }}/index.html">{{ category | first }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It should probably be the accepted answer.