# Ruby sort by multiple fields and multilple directions for different data types

Tags: ruby

I need to write a `multi_sort` method to sort an array of hash which accepts a hash as an argument, eg: { a_sort: 1, display_sort: 1 }. This hash is sort fields and sort direction. (1 means ascending, -1 means descending).

```
items = [ {name: 'Album 1', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 3}, 
          {name: 'Album 2', a_sort: 1, display_sort: 5}, 
          {name: 'Album 3', a_sort: 3, display_sort: 2},
          {name: 'Album 5', a_sort: 1, display_sort: 8}, 
          {name: 'Album 7', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 1}, 
          {name: 'Album 7', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 6} ]

multi_sort(items, {a_sort: 1, display_sort: 1})
```

I can't figure it out after 3 hours. The expected output is the array that is sorted correctly.

```
      [ {name: 'Album 2', a_sort: 1, display_sort: 5},
        {name: 'Album 5', a_sort: 1, display_sort: 8},
        {name: 'Album 3', a_sort: 3, display_sort: 2},
        {name: 'Album 7', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 1}
        {name: 'Album 1', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 3}, 
        {name: 'Album 7', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 6} ]
```

Comment: *"This hash is a sorted field and sorted direction."* - please be more specific. How does `1` indicate a direction? Is the argument order of any importance? What's your expected output?

Comment: @Stefan, I updated. Thanks

Comment: What about the argument / hash key order - is `{ a_sort: 1, display_sort: 1 }` the same as `{ display_sort: 1, a_sort: 1 }`? It would really help to see the expected output for different arguments.

Comment: The hash key order doesn't affect the output. I just updated the expected output.

Comment: So you can't sort by `display_sort` first and then by `a_sort`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. The order of the hash affects the results. I want to sort by a_sort first, then display_sort, in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very interesting problem. I also think the `sort_by` method would be most helpful. 
My solution (for numerical values only) works like this:

```
DIRECTION_MULTIPLIER = { asc: 1, desc: -1 }

def multi_sort(items, order)
  items.sort_by do |item|
    order.collect do |key, direction|
      item[key]*DIRECTION_MULTIPLIER[direction]
    end
  end
end

# ... items ...
multi_sort(items, a_sort: :asc, display_sort: :desc)
```

The idea is to construct a list for each item passed by `sort_by`. This list consists out of all values for which a sort order was given. Hence, we use that Ruby knows that `[1,2]` is smaller than `[1,3]` but greater than `[0,0]`.

An interesting part to note is that the last parameters for the function will be passed as one Hash and the order of these hash pairs *will be maintained*. This "ordered" behavior in Hashes is not necessarily true for all languages, but the [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) states: `Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted`.

**-- Edit for more generality --**

Since, chamnap asked for a more general solution which works with arbitrary data types and `nil`, here a more comprehensive solution which relies on the `<=>` operator:

```
require 'date'
DIRECTION_MULTIPLIER = { asc: 1, desc: -1 }

# Note: nil will be sorted towards the bottom (regardless if :asc or :desc)
def multi_sort(items, order)
  items.sort do |this, that|
    order.reduce(0) do |diff, order|
      next diff if diff != 0 # this and that have differed at an earlier order entry
      key, direction = order
      # deal with nil cases
      next  0 if this[key].nil? && that[key].nil?
      next  1 if this[key].nil?
      next -1 if that[key].nil?
      # do the actual comparison
      comparison = this[key] <=> that[key]
      next comparison * DIRECTION_MULTIPLIER[direction]
    end
  end
end
```

I am using the `sort` method. The block gets called each time the sort function needs to compare to elements. The block shall return -1, 0 or 1 (smaller, equal or higher in the order) for the respective pair. Within this sort block I am going through the `order` hash which contains the key and the direction for a hash value in items. If we have found an earlier difference in order (e.g. the first key was higher) we just return that value. If the past comparisons came up with equal order, we use the `<=>` operator to compare the two elements passed to the sort block (and multiply the result it with -1 if we want descending order). The only annoying thing is to deal with `nil` values, which adds the three lines above the actual comparison.

And here my test code:

```
items = [ {n: 'ABC  ', a:   1, b: Date.today+2},
          {n: 'Huhu ', a: nil, b: Date.today-1},
          {n: 'Man  ', a: nil, b: Date.today},
          {n: 'Woman', a: nil, b: Date.today}, 
          {n: 'DEF  ', a:   7, b: Date.today-1}]
multi_sort(items, b: :asc, a: :desc, n: :asc)
```

On a more general note: Since the logic for sorting becomes a little more complicated, I would wrap the data in actual objects with attributes. Then you could overwrite the `<=>` operator as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808404/4007237).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your code will be broken when working with other data types such as: nil and datetime. How do we solve this?

Comment: I added a new solution to my answer. Is this what you need?

Comment: Sorting by arrays is the way to go! In my simple case, I wanted to sort by a point value descending and then by name ascending, so construction of the array like [-1*user.points, user.name] did the trick!

Answer (score 6):

This only works with numeric values in the hash:

`sort_by` excepts an item to sort by, but since we want to sort by many items we should create a list.

Since we want to be able to decide directions we map each value in this list with either itself (*1) or negative self (*-1) causing the sort to be reversed.

```
items = [ {name: 'Album 1', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 3}, 
          {name: 'Album 2', a_sort: 1, display_sort: 5}, 
          {name: 'Album 3', a_sort: 3, display_sort: 2},
          {name: 'Album 5', a_sort: 1, display_sort: 8}, 
          {name: 'Album 7', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 1}, 
          {name: 'Album 7', a_sort: 5, display_sort: 6} ]

def multi_sort(items, sort_directions)
  items.sort_by do |row|
    sort_directions.map{|key,val| val*row[key]} 
  end
end

puts multi_sort(items, {a_sort: 1, display_sort: -1}) # =>

#{:name=>"Album 5", :a_sort=>1, :display_sort=>8}
#{:name=>"Album 2", :a_sort=>1, :display_sort=>5}
#{:name=>"Album 3", :a_sort=>3, :display_sort=>2}
#{:name=>"Album 7", :a_sort=>5, :display_sort=>6}
#{:name=>"Album 1", :a_sort=>5, :display_sort=>3}
#{:name=>"Album 7", :a_sort=>5, :display_sort=>1}
```

Here is a version that uses sort and is a bit more complicated, can sort any data that can be sorted by the `<=>` operator:

```
def multi_sort(items, sort_directions)
  items.sort do |row1,row2|
    keys = sort_directions.map{|key,val| val*(row1[key]<=>row2[key])}
    keys.find{|x|x!=0} || 0
  end
end

puts multi_sort(items, {a_sort: -1, display_sort: 1}) # =>

#{:name=>"Album 1", :a_sort=>5, :display_sort=>"a"}
#{:name=>"Album 7", :a_sort=>5, :display_sort=>"a"}
#{:name=>"Album 7", :a_sort=>5, :display_sort=>"b"}
#{:name=>"Album 3", :a_sort=>3, :display_sort=>"b"}
#{:name=>"Album 5", :a_sort=>1, :display_sort=>"b"}
#{:name=>"Album 2", :a_sort=>1, :display_sort=>"v"}
```

Here is how it works. Sort takes two arguments (row1,row2), the two items that should be compared and expects a return value of -1, 0 or 1. When arg1>arg2 then -1, when arg2==arg1 then 0, when arg1

So, all we need to to is to figure this out. I take they keys and for each value in the hash I apply the `<=>` using the `map` function. I multiply the result with 1 or -1 to get the reverse effect. Then, I just got through the list of comparisons and pick the first non-zero value. If all columns are the same, the array will be full with zeros, and the sort will call them equal.

Comment: Can you explain me how it works? What if I want to use `#sort` instead of `#sort_by`?

Comment: `sort_by` by evaluates the block once per items, this is much more efficient than `sort` which evaluates the block once of each comparison. You should really never use `sort` unless you really really must.

Comment: can you make to support other data types?

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer and nice explanation. I just wonder why you pick the first non-zero value?

Comment: The list is the result of all comparisons. 1 means A>B, -1 means B>A and 0 mean A=B.  In the example above the  `{a_sort: -1, display_sort: 1}` is the key and the array would be of length 2 where the fisrt element is the result of comparing `a_sort`. `[0,1]` would the translate to: I compared the two elements, and was not able to decide the order based on the first key (`a_sort`) as they were equal. When the algorithm finds a non-zero that means that one of the key were not equal, and it can sort based on that.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple and basic solution to your problem(if I understand your problem correctly) is to use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html). For example, if you want to order elements by `a_sort`(it seems like it in your updated example) field in ascending order:

```
items.sort_by { |x| x[:a_sort] }
```

If you want to sort by two fields, you *need* some law by which sorting will be performed. The most simple random law(useless, but it'll work as an example) would be string concatenation, if we cast these values to string:

```
items.sort_by { |x| x[:a_sort].to_s + x[:display_sort].to_s }
```

If you want to sort by one field, then by another it sound(from your comment), you seem to want grouping. Something like this will be appropriate if you want to sort something less simple than two strings:

```
items.group_by { |x| x[:a_sort] }
  .sort
  .flat_map do |_, a|
    a.sort_by { |x| x[:display_sort] }
  end
```

It's not really efficient, but i think it's general enough to showcase my point.

Comment: I want to sort multiple fields (a_sort and display_sort) in different direction.

Comment: @dredozubov Please use the comments to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Stefan No problem, i'll edit it out after some clarification. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @dredozubov, what if those values have different data types? How to make use of the `#sort` method?

Comment: @Chamnap You should use appropriate sorting functions for your datatypes. Ruby is dynamically typed, so one implementation will make sense for one set of types and blow up with an exception at runtime with other. You can find documentation on `Enumerator#sort` if you click the link i provided in my answer.

Comment: @dredozubov are you sure this part `items.sort_by { |x| x[:a_sort] + x[:display_sort] }` would work as expected? I think this would sum up the numerical values instead of string concatenating.

Comment: @Motine Thanks for pointing it out, i totally forgot to cast these values to strings.